# multiple search forms in reports using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am doing one project by using PHP Mysql. I have finished all the modules now am getting struck in Reports. The client want the report with multiple search options. i have four fields 1). Serial Number, 2). Value, 3). Date, 4). location. if the client select serial number and date means report should be display with selected serial number and also date. But my select query is not working its fetching all the data's.

Comment: determine what data is not provided and don't supply those columns when you construct your AND

Comment: look around timestamp 3:45   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBxcPOxRgeE

Comment: hi Rajendran, here my code.. if(!$sno=='')
 {
  $sql = mysql_query("select * from vaccum_details where serial_number='$sno'");
 }
 
 if(!$vvalue=='')
 {
  $sql = mysql_query("select * from vaccum_details where vaccum_value='$vvalue'");
 }
 
 if(!$date=='')
 {
  $sql = mysql_query("select * from vaccum_details where date='$date'");
 }
 
 if(!$location=='')
 {
  $sql = mysql_query("select * from vaccum_details where location='$location'");
 }

Answer (score 1):

As you have 4 search fields, you have to create your where clause based on this
1)Serial Number, 2). Value, 3). Date, 4). location.

```
if(isset($serial_number)
    $where = "WHERE serial_number = $serial_number"
if(isset($value){
 $where .= " AND VALUE = $value"
}
if(isset($Date){
 $where .= " AND Date= $Date"
}
if(isset($location){
 $where .= " AND location= $location"
}
```

Comment: the == will not work in sql just use = instead also the variables in the sql ($location for instance) will not interpolate with single quotes. Can I suggest you echo the $where variable and test the whole sql statement in an sql client to make sure you're getting the sql in the correct format